# wp_enqueue_scripts with JS script as a string

Tags: php, ajax

isn't there any way to load a script through `wp_enqueue_scripts` and have my script instead of in a file, in a variable declared earlier? Something like:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_check_payment');
function ajax_check_payment() {
    $script = <<<JS
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('asdasd');
        });
    });
    </script>
JS;

    wp_enqueue_script('ajax_check_course_payment', $script, array('jquery'), time());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `wp_enqueue_script` doesn't work that way — the second parameter is for a URL as per the documentation.

But you could use `wp_add_inline_script()` (if there's an enqueue'd script to attach it to) or, as in olden times, just hook in to `wp_head` or `wp_footer`.

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm gonna do... I'll use `wp_footer`. Thanks! :)